# Quick Python Book message_wall01.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering is someone could help me figure out why I keep getting the error AssertionError: Header names/values must be of type str (got b'Content-type')
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2015 20:50:52] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59. The code comes from "The Quick Python Book" from Manning publishing.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def message_wall_app(environ, start_response):
    status = b'200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [(b'Content-type', b'text/html; charset=utf-8')]       
    start_response(status, headers)

    # The returned object is going to be printed
    return ["<h1>Message Wall</h1>"]

httpd = make_server('', 8000, message_wall_app)
print("Serving on port 8000...")

# Serve until process is killed
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the b's from:

```
status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')]
```

And add to  `return ["<h1>Message Wall</h1>"]`. You read `unicode/str` and write `bytes`.

The old docs had a bug where the examples used `b'200 OK'` etc.. which is what the book may have been based on, there is an old bug report [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue11968). The current [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.validate) show the correct usage.

Once you do that you will see the output at `http://localhost:8000/` and without error.

Comment: Thank you. Removing the b's from status and headers and adding it to the return statement making it, "return [b'<h1>Message Wall</h1>']" made everything work. Thanks so much.